# HM question- the graph K4,3

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We've been asked to prove the following:

Prove that you can place K4,3 on the plane with exactly two intersects. then, prove that you can't do it with less intersections.

someone?

Comment: Well, you only have to prove that zero or one intersections are both impossible, and then find an explicit drawing with two intersections. Sound allright? Just experiment a little to find an actual drawing with two intersections. As for zero being impossible, you can use a certain theorem about planarity to directly conclude in that case (K4,3 has a subgraph of interest for this). As for one being impossible, you can try to use the theorem from before again, but this time, argue that there can't be just one intersection (you have two overlapping copies of the same special subgraph so to say).

Comment: seems about right, thanks.